# Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en NodeJS y quiero instalarla en mi tienda de Shopify. Alguien me explica como puedo lograrlo?

Tags: nodejs, shopify

Tengo los permisos que me brindó la App de desarrollo que instalé en mi tienda.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido @JorgeVerde!  Lo siento pero tu pregunta carece de un [example] que nos permita ayudarte. Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento de este sitio y cómo elaborar buenas preguntas. Tal como está ahora es seguro que va a ser cerrada por falta de detalles concretos. Puedes solicitar reabrirla pulsando sobre [edit] para agregar esa información que falta.